# Xcode complains about a non-decodeable instance of a view

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, xcode6, xib

Xcode complains like so about an old project:

[image]

**Could someone provide a way to somehow fix this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point I can only say that you can open your ManMenu.xib in the text editor and go looking for your ABFadingImageView class and see where the error is. It either has a null value or a null reference that is not accepted.

You can probably skip all the menu items. The xib file is loaded with it. At the beginning and end you see the code that is interesting for you. It is not a guarantee that you can fix it, but in the text editor you can change the xml code.